# Biblatex macros for url printing

Tags: biblatex, urls

I'd like to change the "URL:", which appears when quoting an online document, by the `urlfrom` string corresponding to the language I use.

The options I use for `biblatex` are:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,singletitle=true,style=verbose-trad2,bibstyle=verbose,isbn=false,maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}
```

I give you an example:

[image]

The corresponding code is:

```
@ARTICLE{Monnier_democ_1999,
  author = {Monnier, Raymonde},
  title = {Démocratie et Révolution française},
  journal = {Mots},
  year = {1999},
  volume = {59},
  pages = {47--68},
  number = {1},
  publisher = {ENS Editions},
  url = {http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/mots_0243-6450_1999_num_59_1_2547},
  urldate = {2015-04-06}
}
```

In biblatex.def I found the macro that seems to manage the url printing :

```
\newbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\newbibmacro*{url}{\printfield{url}}
\newbibmacro*{urldate}{\printurldate}
```

But I can't see any indication about this "URL:" field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french,]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Monnier_democ_1999,
  author = {Monnier, Raymonde},
  title = {Démocratie et Révolution française},
  journal = {Mots},
  year = {1999},
  volume = {59},
  pages = {47--68},
  number = {1},
  publisher = {ENS Éditions},
  url = {http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/mots_0243-6450_1999_num_59_1_2547},
  urldate = {2015-04-06}
}
\end{filecontents} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, singletitle=true, style=verbose-trad2, bibstyle=verbose, isbn=false, hyperref, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  urlseen = {consult\'e le},
}

 \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{<}\def\UrlRight{>}%
\urlstyle{sf}}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! And does anyone knows how to put the url between <and>, as in this case : <http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/mots_0243-6450_1999_num_59_1_2547> I did not find any \add... type command for that.

Comment: I don't see what you mean exactly. Maybe adding another url? Could you be more explicit?

Comment: I want the last part of the result to be as this :   Disp. a l’adr. : <http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/mots_0243-6450_1999_num_59_1_
2547> (consulté le 06/04/2015).

Comment: Just changing `visité` for `consulté`?

Comment: No. This is due to my modifications of french.lbx  I just want to put the url between greater than "<" and lesser than ">" symbols.

Comment: Oh! You want the hyperlink then?

Comment: So with another url I would have Disp à l'adresse : <www.google.com> (consulté le 06/04/2015). for example

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything. See my updated answer. Does that correspond to what you want?

Comment: I want to have (if my url string in my bib file is url = {www.foobar.com}) this result : Disp. a l’adr. : <www.foobar.com> (consulté le 06/04/2015).

Comment: @Vertex: Is that OK now?